My elif is not working and there are no syntax errors
I am a python newbie, and I'm trying to learn more about conditionals, but my elif condition just won't work to matter what I do. And there are no syntax errors at all! PLS SOMEONE HELP'A ME!!
is_old = False
is_licenced = True

if is_old == True & is_licenced == True:
    print('You are legally allowed to drive')
elif is_old == False & is_licenced == True:
    print("What'd you do, steal this from your parents??")
else:
    print("You can't drive.")



& is bit wise and; you want and for boolean comparisons instead.
The operator precedence table shows that bit operator & has a higher priority than the equality operator ==. Your code is parsed as elif is_old == (False & is_licenced) == True:, so False & is_licensed is evaluated first, which is False & True, which is False. You're left with elif is_old == False == True: which is here False == False == True, which is (False == False) and (False == True), and with one side of the and being False, the whole term evaluates to False.
and has a lower priority than ==, so it behaves as you expect, it compares both sides of the and, and then combines the results with the boolean and operation.
You can also shorten the is_old == True to just is_old and the is_old == False to not is_old:
is_old = False
is_licenced = True

if is_old and is_licenced:
    print('You are legally allowed to drive')
elif not is_old and is_licenced:
    print("What'd you do, steal this from your parents??")
else:
    print("You can't drive.")


False == False == True is not evaluated left-to-right. It is the same as (False == False) and (False == True) and so the result is False. (see Comparisons in the documentation)

I think that you have to change & to 'and' - it should work then
